# neural network gives TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'training')

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

i was trying to train a  fcnn model with tensorflow probability but i get an error that i do not understand. the neural net is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import timeit
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import datetime,os
tfd = tfp.distributions
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def normal_exp(params): 
  return tfd.Normal(loc=params[:,0:1], scale=tf.math.exp(params[:,1:2]))

def NLL(y, distr): 
  return -distr.log_prob(y) 

def create_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Input(shape=(1,)),
    Dense(200,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1, training=True),
    Dense(500,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1, training=True),
    Dense(500,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1, training=True),
    Dense(200,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1, training=True),
    Dense(2),
    tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_exp, name='normal_exp')
])
def train_model():
    model = create_model() 
    model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.0002), loss=NLL)
    logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m    %d-%H%M%S"))
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
    model.fit(x= X_train, y =y_train, epochs=1500, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

train_model()
```

while the error says

```
`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py in validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message) ``
`1172   for kwarg in kwargs:`
`1173     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:`
`-> 1174       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)`
`1175`
`1176`

`` TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'training')`
```

i tried modifying the way the neural network is defined inside Sequential() but  i do not know where is the problem

Comment: The code is incomplete/incorrect. where is `tf.keras`,`tfd`,`tfp` comming from, there is no such import in the code

Comment: @SadraNaddaf i have added them.i forgot to copy them here on stackoverflow but they were defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Sequential API` you can't use `trining=True` in layers inputs as `**kwargs`. But you can use `training=True` in `Functional API` like below:

```
x = Input(shape=(1,))
x = Dense(200,activation="relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.1)(x, training=True)
x = Dense(2)(x)
out = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_exp, name='normal_exp')(x)
```

Your correct code in `Sequential API`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import timeit
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
import datetime,os
tfd = tfp.distributions
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def normal_exp(params): 
  return tfd.Normal(loc=params[:,0:1], scale=tf.math.exp(params[:,1:2]))

def NLL(y, distr): 
  return -distr.log_prob(y) 

def create_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Input(shape=(1,)),
    Dense(200,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(500,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(500,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(200,activation="relu"),
    Dropout(0.1),
    Dense(2),
    tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_exp, name='normal_exp')
])
def train_model():
    model = create_model() 
    model.compile(Adam(learning_rate=0.0002), loss=NLL)
    logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m    %d-%H%M%S"))
    tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
    model.fit(x= X_train, y =y_train, epochs=2, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

    
X_train = np.random.rand(10,1)
y_train = np.random.rand(10)

    
X_val = np.random.rand(10,1)
y_val = np.random.rand(10)

train_model()
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step - loss: 1.1478 - val_loss: 1.0427
Epoch 2/2
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 158ms/step - loss: 1.1299 - val_loss: 1.0281
```

Comment: but i use them  for bayesian inference. if i write 
inputs = Input(shape=(1,))
hidden = Dense(200,activation="relu")(inputs)
hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
hidden = Dense(500,activation="relu")(hidden)
hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
hidden = Dense(500,activation="relu")(hidden)
hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
hidden = Dense(200,activation="relu")(hidden)
hidden = Dropout(0.1)(hidden, training=True)
params_mc = Dense(2)(hidden)
dist_mc = tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(normal_exp, name='normal_exp')(params_mc) 

it works

Comment: @Pikappa, OK, but why do you want training `DropOut`, do you know about the dropout layer?!

Comment: they are used as a regularization mechanics in training phase but if you keeps them active during the inference phase they allow to get an approximate bayesian inference

Comment: i got it from here https://github.com/tensorchiefs/dl_book/blob/master/chapter_08/nb_ch08_03.ipynb

Comment: The point is that you cannot supply this argument in the layer constructor, it has to go into the `call` function. Since you never use the `call` function in the `Sequential` API, this seems like the wrong tool for the job. The Functional API should be better: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: ah ok, i was using the functional api, but i thought it would work with the sequential too

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Dropout` layers don't have a `training` argument. When using `model.fit`, `training` will be appropriately set to True automatically, and in other contexts, you can set the kwarg explicitly to True when calling the layer :

```
tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2, noise_shape=None, seed=None)(dense, training=True)
```